# An algorithm for aggregating similar contiguous values within 2D array into groups

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, algorithm

I have a `2D array` that contains a different number of columns each time.
I made an example with `row_Count = 7` and `column_Count = 7`, like the picture below:

[Error Range Table Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaA3M.png)

Now I want to make an algorithm with c# for aggregating similar contiguous 
(neighbouring) values in this 2D array into groups.

What is the goal ?

I want to make groups for the error ranges.
As you see in the picture, I made 14 groups from the values. 
Surely we can make the groups in different ways. 
My goal is to get as few groups as possible.

So now From the image above we can say :

- When the temperature less than -20 c° and the pressure from 0 to 9 Bar, then the error range is : 1. `group1`.
- When the temperature (from 20 c° to 80 c°) and the pressure (from 0 to 9 Bar), then the error range is : 1. `group2`.
- When the temperature (from -20 c° to 80 c°) and the pressure is 0 Bar, then the error range is : 1. `group3`.
- When the temperature (bigger than 80 c°) and the pressure (from 0 to 9 Bar), then the error range is : 5. `group5`.
- When the temperature (from 5 c° to 20 c°) and the pressure from (0 Bar to 1 bar), then the error range is : 4. `group6`.
  ...etc

I changed the example to make it clearer.
I hope that it is better now.

Comment: For me it's unclear what it is you want. Sometimes you say in stepx from level_y to level_z but in another place you talk about in level_x from stepY to stepZ. I see no correlation between how you choose step or level in combination with the x, y and z values and the group numbering. Could you expand your answer to contain exactly what you would like as output given this input?

Comment: Consider using [Connected-component labeling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

Comment: I see 41 groups in your example. Since that's much higher than your estimate, I assume that you need to describe the goal in a little more detail. For example, in column `"step3"`, are there any groups, or would you just skip `"step3"`?